# Using multiple JOINs with several conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to use several helper tables to display the status of a timer. (Browser with php)
 The helper tables are used to be able to switch between languages.

Here the helper table for Timer Types:

```
+-------------+------+------------------+
| lfdLanguage | Type | TText            |
+-------------+------+------------------+
|           0 |    0 | Puls             |
|           0 |    1 | steigende Flanke |
|           0 |    2 | fallende Flanke  |
|           1 |    0 | Pulse            |
|           1 |    1 | rissing edge     |
|           1 |    2 | falling edge     |
+-------------+------+------------------+
```

and for Day Active:

```
+-------------+--------+--------+
| lfdLanguage | Active | ACText |
+-------------+--------+--------+
|           0 |      0 | _      |
|           0 |      1 | X      |
|           1 |      0 | _      |
|           1 |      1 | X      |
+-------------+--------+--------+
```

Usually I use equi joins, but here I would like to display the status of the days (i.e. RunMonday, ...) using the same helper table.

Using the following statement without the `AND  WHERE HTT.lfdLanguage = 0` works fine.

But with the where statement I can't exexute. I get an error:

> ('ERROR 1064 (42000): .....')

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  T.lfdTimer,
  T.Active,
  T.Name,
  T.Type,         HTT.TText,
  T.RunMonday,    HTDA1.ACText,
  T.RunTuesday,   HTDA2.ACText,
  T.RunWednesady, HTDA3.ACText,
  T.RunThursday,  HTDA4.ACText,
  T.RunFriday,    HTDA5.ACText,
  T.RunSaturday,  HTDA6.ACText,
  T.RunSunday,    HTDA7.ACText
FROM
  Timer T
INNER JOIN HelpTimerType      HTT   ON (T.Type         = HTT.Type     AND  WHERE HTT.lfdLanguage = 0);
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA1 ON (T.RunMonday    = HTDA1.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA2 ON (T.RunTuesday   = HTDA2.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA3 ON (T.RunWednesady = HTDA3.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA4 ON (T.RunThursday  = HTDA4.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA5 ON (T.RunFriday    = HTDA5.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA6 ON (T.RunSaturday  = HTDA6.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA7 ON (T.RunSunday    = HTDA7.Active) 
;
```

Any idea how to include the language selection into the JOINs?

All help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Next time pls share the full error message! It is completely pointless to provide just the error number, but not the description.

Answer (score 1):

The where clause comes **after** all the joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  T.lfdTimer,
  T.Active,
  T.Name,
  T.Type,         HTT.TText,
  T.RunMonday,    HTDA1.ACText,
  T.RunTuesday,   HTDA2.ACText,
  T.RunWednesady, HTDA3.ACText,
  T.RunThursday,  HTDA4.ACText,
  T.RunFriday,    HTDA5.ACText,
  T.RunSaturday,  HTDA6.ACText,
  T.RunSunday,    HTDA7.ACText
FROM
  Timer T
INNER JOIN HelpTimerType      HTT   ON (T.Type         = HTT.Type)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA1 ON (T.RunMonday    = HTDA1.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA2 ON (T.RunTuesday   = HTDA2.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA3 ON (T.RunWednesady = HTDA3.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA4 ON (T.RunThursday  = HTDA4.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA5 ON (T.RunFriday    = HTDA5.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA6 ON (T.RunSaturday  = HTDA6.Active)
 LEFT JOIN HelpTimerDayActive HTDA7 ON (T.RunSunday    = HTDA7.Active)
 WHERE HTT.lfdLanguage = 0
;
```

Comment: I wanted to select the correct language on all tables. 
Even a lot more are involved.
Thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
WHERE
```

from your inner join, this is wrong syntax.

Comment: I knew it was something trivial. :)
Thank you very much for your support.
Works perfect also with more help tables.
The timer table is quite large.
Thanks again